# Read a specific word from a text file and then save the next word

Tags: python, file

I need to read from a text file that looks like this:

```
football 1
basketball 2
hockey 0
tennis 2
...
```

where there are x number of lines, each one with a sport and a number.  I'm given a sport and i have to save the number of that sport in a variable, but i cant find a good way to do it.

Comment: Would you like to show some python code if you're going to tag with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a few options here. The simplest is to just iterate through the file object using standard python.

```
# This will only get the first occurrence
with open("sportfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        curr_sport, num = line.split()
        if curr_sport==sport:
            break
```

If you have multiple occurrences you can store the numbers in a list - or you can sum them if you don't need specificity... depends on the problem at hand.

```
sport = 'football' # for example
football_nums = []
with open("sportfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        curr_sport, num = line.split()
        if curr_sport==sport:
            football_nums.append(num)
```

See the docs "https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files" for info on file handles in python.

If you need to translate the file into a python structure that you can query to find any sport and corresponding number you could use pandas (might be overkill but I love pandas :-))

```
df = pd.read_csv('sportfile.txt', sep = ' ')
df.columns = ['sport', 'num']
df[df.sport=='football'] # returns all rows where the sport is football.
```

pandas `.read_csv()` is crazy detailed and powerful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Better to use `current_sport, num = line.split()` to avoid two calls to `split()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to try this. Just tested the quick sample in shell.

```
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = "football"
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sport, number = line.split()
        if sport == key:
            print "{}, {}".format(sport, number)
            break
    else:
        print "{} not found".format(key)
```